# Jython : SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, jython

am getting a syntax error in my code. Can anyone say what's wrong in the syntax? I am new to this language, don't have much of an idea.

Error Message:

> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "jdbcconnection.jy";
>   exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from
>   Jython: Traceback (innermost last): (no code object) at line 0 File
>   "", line 13 AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope
>   Node='+nodeName+',Server='+serverName' -databaseType Oracle
>   -providerType "Oracle JDBC Driver" -implementationType "Connection pool data source" - name "Oracle JDBC Driver" -description "Oracle
>   JDBC Driver" -classpath [${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar]
>   -nativePath "" ]') ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

My code:

```
import sys

def jdbcoracle(nodeName,serverName):
        print 'Create JDBC provider'
    AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node='+nodeName+',Server='+serverName' -databaseType Oracle -providerType "Oracle JDBC Driver" -implementationType "Connection pool data source" -name "Oracle JDBC Driver" -description "Oracle JDBC Driver" -classpath [${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar] -nativePath "" ]')
    AdminTask.createJDBCProvider('[-scope Node='+nodeName+',Server='+serverName' -databaseType Oracle -providerType "Oracle JDBC Driver" -implementationType "XA data source" -name "Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)" -description "Oracle JDBC Driver (XA)" -classpath [${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar] -nativePath "" ]')
        AdminConfig.save()  
    print 'JDBC provider created'   
#-------------------------------------
# Main Application starts from here
#-------------------------------------
global nodeName, cellName
nodeName = sys.argv[0]
serverName = sys.argv[1]
jdbcoracle(nodeName,serverName)
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct or it's just incorrect formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax would be invalid in any language. You have `'...Server='+serverName' ...'` - you are missing a `+` before the reopening of the quote.

Of course, you should not be building up strings like that; you should be using one of the many string formatting features available in Python, for example:

```
'[-scope Node={},Server={} -databaseType...'.format(nodeName, serverName)
```

I suspect you also mean `ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH` to be an interpolated variable, but only you know where that is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: Can you please type the syntax for the my case. I am nw in python scripting

Comment: I just did. And as I said, the syntax would be just as invalid in Java as it is in Python.